# AttributeError: 'Spider' object has no attribute 'table'

Tags: python, oop, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy. I have a spider that starts with:

```
class For_Spider(Spider):

    name = "for"
#    table = 'hello' # creating dummy attribute. will be overwritten

    def start_requests(self):

        self.table = self.dc # dc is passed in
```

I have the following pipeline :

```
class DynamicSQLlitePipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # Here, you get whatever value was passed through the "table" parameter
        table = getattr(crawler.spider, "table")
        return cls(table)

    def __init__(self,table):
        try:
            db_path = "sqlite:///"+settings.SETTINGS_PATH+"\\data.db"
            db = dataset.connect(db_path)
            table_name = table[0:3]  # FIRST 3 LETTERS
            self.my_table = db[table_name]
```

When I start the spider with:

```
scrapy crawl for -a dc=input_string -a records=1
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'For_Spider' object has no attribute 'table'
```

If I uncomment 'table' , the program will start. I'm confused about why 'table' works but self.table does not. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

`table` will work because it is a class attribute of `For_Spider` and `self.table` is just inside the function scope. `self` indicates the instance itself, so in that case inside the function you don't need to use it (unless you define it in `__init__`).
If you'll try defining `self.table` outside the function scope you'll get an error.

Also, try using `__dict__` on both classes to see their attributes and functions
With table commented:

> {'**doc**': None, 'start_requests': , 'name': 'for', '**module**': 'builtins'})

As you can see, no `table` attribute

With table not commented:

> {'**doc**': None, 'start_requests': , 'table': 'hello', 'name': 'for', '**module**': 'builtins'})

I hope that was clear :>

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I guess I'm confused about class attribute vs instance attribute. I thought they were essentially the same.

Comment: also, more practically, I would like to pass a 'table'parameter from the command line to dynamically set a table variable that is accessible to the pipeline.