# Passing scrapy instance (not class) attribute to pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy. I have a pipieline that starts with:

```
class DynamicSQLlitePipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # Here, you get whatever value was passed through the "table" parameter
        table = getattr(crawler.spider, "table")
        return cls(table)

    def __init__(self,table):
        try:
            db_path = "sqlite:///"+settings.SETTINGS_PATH+"\\data.db"
            db = dataset.connect(db_path)
            table_name = table[0:3]  # FIRST 3 LETTERS
            self.my_table = db[table_name]
```

My spider starts with:

```
class For_Spider(Spider):

    name = "for"
    table = 'hello' # creating dummy attribute. will be overwritten

    def start_requests(self):

        self.table = self.dc # dc is passed in
```

When I start the spider with:

```
scrapy crawl for -a dc=mystring -a records=1
```

dc is passed in as a instance attribute (not a class attribute)

How do I pass this instance attribute to my pipeline so that I can dynamically set the table name in my pipeline? What I have now works for a class attribute.

Comment: aren't you already doing that in the pipeline constructor?

Comment: If I understand correctly :         table = getattr(crawler.spider, "table") in the pipeline constructor  is getting a class attribute ( which I have to set statically). I want to be able to pass in the table name in as a parameter so I can set in from the command line.

Comment: not correct, because `crawler.spider` already has the `Spider` instance, not the class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good understanding of this as yet. Would you mind expanding on that. My original question yesterday btw  was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955005/attributeerror-spider-object-has-no-attribute-table

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler

Comment: see [Using arguments in scrapy pipeline on __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513707/using-arguments-in-scrapy-pipeline-on-init)