# What is the relationship between the crawler object with spider and pipeline objects?

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

I'm working with scrapy. I have a pipieline that starts with:

```
class DynamicSQLlitePipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # Here, you get whatever value was passed through the "table" parameter
        table = getattr(crawler.spider, "table")
        return cls(table)

    def __init__(self,table):
        try:
            db_path = "sqlite:///"+settings.SETTINGS_PATH+"\\data.db"
            db = dataset.connect(db_path)
            table_name = table[0:3]  # FIRST 3 LETTERS
            self.my_table = db[table_name]
```

I've been reading through https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#crawler-api , which contains:

> The main entry point to Scrapy API is the Crawler object, passed to extensions through the from_crawler class method. This object provides access to all Scrapy core components, and it’s the only way for extensions to access them and hook their functionality into Scrapy.

but still do not understand the from_crawler method, and the crawler object. What is the relationship between the crawler object with spider and pipeline objects? How and when is a crawler instantiated? Is a spider a subclass of crawler? I've asked [Passing scrapy instance (not class) attribute to pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963416/passing-scrapy-instance-not-class-attribute-to-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment82900430_47963416), but I don't understand how the pieces fit together.

Comment: see [scrapy's architecture](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)

Comment: Thank you, but crawler is not on that diagram.

Comment: if I understand correctly `crawler` is object which runs engine to do all this things on image - get url, read data from server, uses `spider` only to parse data, uses pipeline and midleware to change data and make other things like writing to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Crawler`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html?highlight=crawler#crawler-api) is actually one of the most important objects in the Scrapy's architecture. It is a central piece of the crawling execution logic which *"glues" a lot of other pieces together*:

> The main entry point to Scrapy API is the `Crawler` object, passed to
>   extensions through the from_crawler class method. This object provides
>   access to all Scrapy core components, and it’s the only way for
>   extensions to access them and hook their functionality into Scrapy.

A crawler or multiple crawlers are controlled by the `CrawlerRunner` or the `CrawlerProcess` instance.

Now that `from_crawler` method which is available on lots of Scrapy components is just a way for these components to get access to the `crawler` instance that is running this particular component.

Also, look at the [`Crawler`, `CrawlerRunner` and `CrawlerProcess` actual implementations](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/crawler.py).

And, what I personally found helpful in order to better understand how Scrapy works internally was to run a spider from a script - [check out these detailed step-by-step instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27744766/771848).

Comment: Are spider and pipelines included in "scrapy components " ?

Comment: @user61629 yeah, I've loosely included them under the "components" term.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind looking at my follow up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981620/scrapy-dynamically-passing-parameter-from-command-line-to-pipeline